# How to make two dimensional list using an existing one dimensional list for hashing?

Tags: python, list, hashmap

I have a list of integers like: `[10, 20, 50, 30]` and I want to count the occurrence of these integers in another list.
For example if `10` in the first list comes twice in the second list with rest of the integers occuring only once, then the output must be: `[[10:2], [20:1], [50:1], [30:]]`

I tried with the below code but I'm getting an error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'extend'`. What am I doing wrong ?

```
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    s[i].append([])
    for j in range(0,len(ar)):
        if s[i]==ar[j]:
            s[i][0]+=1
```

I am trying to achieve a sort of hash map, please share any better approach you may have. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @loksoni! If you found my answer helpful, please consider [voting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), according to StackOverflow rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object is ideally suited for the task.

```
from collections import Counter

wanted = [10, 20, 50, 30]

other_list = [10, 20, 10, 40, 60, 50, 100, 70]

wanted_set = frozenset(wanted)
counts = Counter([number for number in other_list if number in wanted_set])

print(counts)

# Access the count for every number.
for number in counts:
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(number, counts[number]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use both Dictionary comprehension in Python:

```
s = [10, 20, 50, 30]
{curr: s.count(curr) for curr in s}
Out[0]: {10: 1, 20: 1, 50: 1, 30: 1}
```

You can also use Python collection Counter like this:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(s)
Out[0]: Counter({10: 1, 20: 1, 50: 1, 30: 1})
```

References:

- List and Dictionary Comprehension in Python - [here](https://timothybramlett.com/List_and_Dict_Comprehensions_in_Python.html)
- Counter object documentation - [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

Good Luck!

Comment: `{curr: s.count(curr) for curr in s}` is needlessly inefficient. O(N^2) when you can do it in O(N).

Comment: I gave both options haven't I?